# Which type of cooling result to a larger volume of cooled specimen?

Tags: material-science

You have certain amount of metal liquid at very high temperature. Option 1: you thermally quench it. (ultra fast cooling)
Option 2: You allow it to cool down slowly.
Which option will result in a block which features the larger volume and why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slowly cooling down a metal (annealing) leads to stronger and more ordered bonds being formed between the atoms. If the object is better structured, it should have lesser volume. Hence, thermally quenching it should result in a larger volume of metal.

Answer (score 1):

Slow cooling prevents thermal stresses from being frozen into the block and so will result in the smaller volume.